# Поля поиска gridview для связанных таблиц yii2

Tags: yii2

Сделал связь между таблицами, чтобы в основном gridview выводить данные из них. Все нормально работает но исчезло поле поиска под названием колонки. Для таблиц, которые связаны с основной напрямую, с помощью настроек в OrderSearch в rules вернул поля поиска. Есть колонка с более сложной связью:

```
public function getType(){
    return $this->hasOne(DeliveryTypes::className(), ['delivery-types_code' => 'order_delivery_code'])
            ->viaTable('order_delivery', ['order_id' => 'order_id']);
}
```

Делаю так

```
$query->joinWith('type');
$query->alias('t');

$query->andFilterWhere([
        't.order_id' => $this->order_id,
```

Во вью

```
[
   'attribute' => 'order_id',
   'value' => 'type.delivery-types_name'
],
```

Все нормально выводит, при запросе поиска ошибок не выдает, но ничего не ищет. Как можно решить?

[screen](http://joxi.ru/krD0ewjin6Zvrp)

Comment: а вы в Search модель это поле добавили? http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/

Comment: @MasterAlex этот кусок кода из Search модели `$query->joinWith('type');
$query->alias('t');

$query->andFilterWhere([
        't.order_id' => $this->order_id,`

Comment: да, но этот кусок не добавляет это поле в Search-модель, нужно написать где-нибудь вначале: `public $type;`, а в `rules` добавить правило валидации для `type`, посмотрите по ссылке, что я выше указал

Comment: @MasterAlex спасибо, разобрался. если оформите как ответ, с удовольствием отмечу.